# What does Proof. simpl. reflexivity. Qed. mean in Coq?

Tags: coq

I'm reading the book Software Foundations and got stuck at the very beginning.

The author defined a boolean type and common operations:

```
Inductive bool: Type :=
  | true 
  | false.

Definition orb (b1: bool) (b2: bool) : bool :=
  match b1 with
  | true => true
  | false => b2
  end.
```

So let's say we want to prove the correctness of the or function.
The author wrote a test followed by a proof:

```
Example test_orb1: (orb true false) = true.
Proof. simpl. reflexivity. Qed.
```

Could someone explain to me what *simpl. reflexivity* mean? Is there any other way we can prove this simple test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`simpl` is a tactic evaluating the goal. In your case, after executing it, the goal will be left to `true = true`.
`reflexivity` is a tactic discharging goals of the shape `x = x` (in its simplest incarnation). What it does under the hood is to provide the proof term `eq_refl : x = x` as a solution to the current proof obligation.

Now, there are many ways to achieve this thing that ultimately will produce the same (rather trivial) proof `eq_refl` (try doing `Print test_orb1.`). First, the `simpl` operation is not needed because Coq will do some computations when applying a term (in particular when calling `reflexivity`). Second, you could obtain the same effect as `reflexivity` by calling `constructor`, `apply eq_refl` or `refine eq_refl`. These are tactics with different goals but that happen to coincide here.